# how to change the visibility of an element in a certain screen size with css

Tags: html, css

I want to make a site where the main menu collapses at 1000 px and a drop-down menu appears at below 100px.
I have written the following HTML and CSS.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  div.topnav {
    display: none;
  }
}
    
@media screen and (max-width:1001px) {
  div.navbar {
    display:none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <a href="#">text</a>
  <a href="#">text</a>
  <a href="#">text</a>
  <a href="#" style="float:right">text</a>
</div>

<div class="navbar"><a href="#">text</a></div>
<div class="navbar"><a href="#">text</a></div>
<div class="navbar"><a href="#">text</a></div>
<div class="navbar"><a href="#">text</a></div>
```

The div with the class `topnav` is collapsing below 1000px but the divs with the class `navbar` are not appearing. What can I do?
Is there any way to do this without Javascript because, for now I am practicing only HTML and CSS.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. It's `min-width` not `mix-width`.
2. You have `display: none;` on both media queries. Change the queries like below.
3. You need to hide `navbar` above `1000px`

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
div.navbar{ 
 display:block;
}
div.topnav{ 
 display:none;
}
}

@media screen and (min-width:1001px) {
div.navbar{ 
 display:none;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
     <a href="#">text</a>
     <a href="#">text</a>
     <a href="#">text</a>
     <a href="#" style="float:right">text</a>
 </div>

<div class="navbar"><a href="#">text</a></div>
<div class="navbar"><a href="#">text</a></div>
<div class="navbar"><a href="#">text</a></div>
<div class="navbar"><a href="#">text</a></div>
```